# How to access an array in Perl passed through Ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl

I am calling a Perl script from HTML using jquery ajax, with given array.

```
var items = [
    { "itemname": "item1", "mrpprice": 1999, "sellprice" : 21.50, "quantity": 2},
    { "itemname": "item2", "mrpprice": 1999, "sellprice" : 22.50, "quantity": 1}
];

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/cgi-bin/submit_order.pl", // URL of the Perl script
    data: { itemsArray : items },
    success: function(data)
    { alert ("success")}
});
```

and reading the CGI param in perl file like this.

```
my @values = $cgi->param('items[]');
```

But not able to access the values in Perl file. I am using the following syntax for accessing.

```
print $values[0]{'quantity'};
```

Can anyone help in what in wrong in this, and what is the correct way to access. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't `$cgi->param('items[]')` be `$cgi->param('itemsArray[]')`

Comment: Tried $cgi->param('itemsArray[]'). Result is same.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $cgi->param` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things potentially wrong here.

```
type: "GET"
```

If you want to send data in a request body, you need to use POST. Even if you were trying to use a query string here -- don't.  There's nothing to be gained that way.  POST is much tidier in this scenario.

Next, this is not a form, and what you are passing is not form data.  This:

```
dataType: "json",
data: { itemsArray : items }
```

Creates a plain serialized array in json format.  It doesn't have any kind of label ("itemsArray" or "items") associated with it -- that's the data you are serializing on the client.  This is all fine, that's exactly what you want (just again, it's not form encoded, it's json).  It will look like `[{ "itemname": "item1", "mrpprice": 1999, "sellprice" : 21.50, "quantity": 2},{ "itemname": "item2", "mrpprice": 1999, "sellprice" : 22.50, "quantity": 1}]`.  See how this is your js array serialized into a string?  That's json.  But "itemName" or "item" -- the label on the variable -- is not part of the variable's *content.*  And all you are sending is the content.  Again, that's what you want.

I am not sure if the CGI module has a way to deal with this, but I would just skip it -- CGI scripts receive input on `STDIN`, the CGI module just parses this for you.  However, it expects form data, and again, that's not what this is.  But you can parse STDIN yourself, or rather, read STDIN and get the perl JSON module to parse it for you.

I'm sure you can still use a .cgi script to do this, just you need to handle the raw input.  *This means really skipping the CGI module, or it will steal your input.  So don't `use CGI`. Omit that module.*  The server will pass you the raw post body on STDIN because the script is registered with the server as a CGI executatble -- you don't need any perl modules at all for that to happen.  So the first thing is to read the input:

```
my $json= "";
while (<STDIN>) {
    $json .= $_;
}
```

That will be the serialized string  from the POST body.  To turn it into a perl array:

```
use JSON::XS;

my $arrayRef = decode_json($json);
```

There is a pure perl version of the module as well.  There both available and [documented](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.59/lib/JSON.pm) on CPAN.